# page.has_content?() vs. expect(page).to have_content

Tags: selenium, cucumber, capybara

Hi people from StackOverflow,

I'm taking over someone's work, and my predecessor created a testset using Cucumber&Capybara&Selenium.
I'm familiar with the lot, but I've got a question concerning his way of finding text on a page.

His implementation:

> expect(page).to have_content(text)

My implementation:

> page.has_content?(text)

What I've noticed is that the first implementation often fails because the automation is 'too quick' for the website to load its page. The latter seems a more robust implementation, perhaps because of its simplicity?

Can someone tell me if there's a right or a wrong, or whether these two are fundamentally different. Because I've been trying to search the web but have not really found a solid conclusion..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`have_content` raises an exception when it's expectation fails and should be used much more often in most test suites than has_content?.  `has_content?` is basically just a wrapper around have_content that catches the exception and returns true or false, and is for use with conditionals

```
if page.has_content?(...)
  # click something
else
  # click something else
end
```

Your predecessor is using Capybara correctly since if you are testing to make sure a page has specific content you should be using `have_content`. `has_content?` will never fail the test (just silently return false and continue on). If your `have_content` assertions are failing because the site is too slow you probably need to increase `Capybara.default_max_wait_time` (or figure out why page load times are so long)

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation! I was mostly trying to figure out why it was set up with the 'have content'. Your explanation makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

Ummm... I think that there is one more thing. 
expect(page).to_have_content(text) is Rspec method while page.has_content?(text) is Minitest method. It is just depend what type of testing you use in your project. I guess.